# QT Creator | Error LNK2019 | Opencv in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, lnk2019

I integrated opencv in QT creator. I want to use my camera and display the frames in the mainwindow. After compiling a simple code, where I only want to output a simple message, I get an error (German language) Like:

> videocap.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes
>   externes Symbol ""public: __cdecl
>   cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(void)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QEAA@XZ)"
>   in Funktion ""public: void __cdecl videoCap::playVideo(void)"
>   (?playVideo@videoCap@@QEAAXXZ)".

Code:

```
void videoCap:: playVideo(){

  VideoCapture *cap = new VideoCapture();
  if(!cap->isOpened()){

    cout<< "nope" << endl;

  }else{

    cout << "dope" << endl;
  }
}
```

Can you explain me what I am doing wrong please ?

Comment: Read: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: add all the opencv libraries to the linker settings. And make sure that opencv was built with the same compiler that you are using in QtCreator.